# Porque o app fecha quando clico no edit1?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

Pessoal o problema é  o seguinte, eu clico no botão de criar um novo form ,edit1 recebe o foco, teclado digital aparece quando clico na letra a por exemplo o app fecha, porque será??
Alguém pode ajudar..?

```
procedure Tformadhor.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  action := TCloseAction.caFree;
  formadhor:=nil;
  formrel.somarel(usua.Id);
  formrel.Show;
end;

procedure Tformadhor.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  edpub.SetFocus;
end;

procedure Tformadhor.Rectangle3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  close;
end;

procedure Tformadhor.Rectangle5Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  salvareg;
  MultiView1.HideMaster;
end;

procedure Tformadhor.salvareg;
var 
  reg:TRegrel;
  db:TDM2;
begin
  reg:=TRegrel.create('null',m,y,strtoint(edpub.Text),strtoint(editvid.Text),
    edithora.Text,strtoint(editrev.Text),strtoint(editest.Text));
  db:=TDM2.Create(nil);
  if db.salvareg(usua,reg) then
    Showmessage('Salvo com Sucesso!!');
  db.DisposeOf;
end;

procedure Tformadhor.setusu(usu: TUsuario; nomemes: string; mes, ano: Integer);
begin
  Labnome.Text:=usu.nomecomp;
  labmes.Text:=nomemes;
  usua:=TUsuario.create('clone','','','',0);
  usua.clone(usu);
  m:=mes;
  y:=ano;
end;
```

Comment: Sem o log de erro fica difícil saber.

Comment: O problema e q o meu delphi e o xe7....

Comment: Você não tem acesso ao LogCat do dispositivo ou emulador?

Comment: Tem nao o android studio bugo a pasta android-sdk vou ter q baixar tudo d novo

Comment: Não tem nenhum comando no evento OnChange do TEdit?

Comment: não tem não...tem uma idéia do q pode ser...?

Comment: posta o Código!

Comment: O código é bem simples...não tem nada de anormal...mas toda ajuda é bem vinda..!!!!

Comment: pelo q percebi até agora o problema tá na troca do foco de edit1 pro outro.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa de um HotFix para o compilador, muito provável que o JNI que esta sendo utilizado não suporta a versão do Android que esta gerando.

O Hotfix depende da versão do Delphi que esta utilizando e também da versão do Android que pretende compilar.

[Fonte](https://cc.embarcadero.com/item/30110)

Comment: Essa é uma possibilidade real. Veja se consegue o Delphi XE7 Update 1 ou algum hotfix, que deve ajudar!

Comment: alguém sabe quem tem o arq baixado não consigo baixa da embarcador....

Comment: Era isso mesmo....atualizei e ficou 10/10...Obrigado...

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente algumas melhorias de código para evitar dores de cabeça futuras:

1. Se você usa firemonkey, isso daqui:

```
procedure Tformadhor.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  action := TCloseAction.caFree;
  formadhor:=nil;
  formrel.somarel(usua.Id);
  formrel.Show;
end;
```

Ficaria muito mais simples só de fazer assim:

```
procedure Tformadhor.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  formrel.somarel(usua.Id);
  formrel.Show;

  Self.close;
end;
```

Se a Thread travar nesse momento, como o método já foi disparado, seu app simplesmente vai fechar sem erro algum. É melhor você não colocar código nenhum nesse evento e fazer essa chamada a outro form informando o ID através de algum outro método, por exemplo:

```
procedure geraRelatorio(pID: integer);
begin
  if not Assigned(formrel) then
    Application.CreateForm(Tformrel, formrel);
  formrel.somarel(pID);
  formrel.Show;
  Self.Close;
end;
```

Como o Firemonkey é um framework orientado a Interfaces, a simples chamada ao método onClose ou onCloseQuery já ativa o `destructor TObject.destroy` que seta a referência da interface pra ser destruída, porque ela saiu do escopo. Só não destroi se ela for atrelada a um form que é o form principal da aplicação.

2. Cada método abaixo tem memory Leak:

```
procedure Tformadhor.salvareg;
var 
  reg:TRegrel;
  db:TDM2;
begin
  reg:=TRegrel.create('null',m,y,strtoint(edpub.Text),strtoint(editvid.Text),
    edithora.Text,strtoint(editrev.Text),strtoint(editest.Text));
  db:=TDM2.Create(nil);
  if db.salvareg(usua,reg) then
    Showmessage('Salvo com Sucesso!!');
  db.DisposeOf;
end;

procedure Tformadhor.setusu(usu: TUsuario; nomemes: string; mes, ano: Integer);
begin
  Labnome.Text:=usu.nomecomp;
  labmes.Text:=nomemes;
  usua:=TUsuario.create('clone','','','',0);
  usua.clone(usu);
  m:=mes;
  y:=ano;
end;
```

Vamos por partes - (Jack ~1980):

```
procedure Tformadhor.salvareg;
var 
  reg: TRegrel;
  db: TDM2;
begin
// Encontrei um descendente de JAVA aqui gente! Construtor amarrado é coisa de JAVAicano
  reg := TRegrel.create('null', m, y, strtoint(edpub.Text), strtoint(editvid.Text),
    edithora.Text, strtoint(editrev.Text), strtoint(editest.Text));
  db := TDM2.Create(nil);
  try
    if db.salvareg(usua, reg) then
      Showmessage('Salvo com Sucesso!!');
  finally
    db.DisposeOf;
    reg.DisposeOf;
  end;
end;
```

```
procedure Tformadhor.setusu(usu: TUsuario; nomemes: string; mes, ano: Integer);
begin
  Labnome.Text := usu.nomecomp;
  labmes.Text := nomemes;
  // Mais uma ocorrência JAVAicana aqui
  usua := TUsuario.create('clone','','','',0);
  try
  { usua não tá definido aqui no escopo do método, se for uma propriedade da
classe, será eliminado juntamente do form, porém se for uma var você quem precisa
matar a instância criada em runtime }
  //usua.clone(usu);
  { Porém, ao simplesmente passar o ponteiro de um objeto para outro, como é o 
caso abaixo, você pode eliminar o objeto usua ou usu uma vez que os 2 representam
a mesma coisa, então ao eliminar um deles, você está liberando a memória pra
todas as instâncias onde aquele setor de memória foi usado }
    usua := usu;
    // faz alguma coisa com o usuario
    m := mes;
    y := ano;
  finally
    usua.DisposeOf;
  end;
end;
```

3. Agora que melhoramos o código daquilo que você compartilhou, de acordo com os passos que você seguiu, esse código aqui é onde ocasionaria o `hang` da sua aplicação:

```
procedure Tformadhor.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  edpub.SetFocus;
end;
```

Porém somente setar foco pra um controle não causa problemas, teria que confirmar se o seu edit não possui algum evento `onTyping`, `onChange`, `onEnter`, `onExit`, `onMouseMove`, `onMouseDown` que são eventos que ocorrem simultaneamente na thread principal, dependendo do aparelho e do que você colocar nesses eventos, sua aplicação simplesmente aborta. Se houver algum evento nesses pontos, certifique-se de utilizar Threads para chamar esses métodos porque aí você consegue evitar possíveis abortos da aplicação.

Sempre evite realizar processamentos no mobile, procure deixar o processamento de qualquer coisa para o back-end, no mobile faça coisas simples, coisas leves, seu usuário agradece por isso!